# How to automatically enable custom dev tools formatters using dev tools API?

Tags: electron, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'd like to enable the "Custom formatters" setting in my Electron app's dev tools as described here: https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer/issues/36#issuecomment-285956783

Enabling the setting manually is possible, but I'd like to do it **automatically** when dev tools is opened so that other developers don't have to remember to do it themselves.

Is it possible to automatically enable this setting with [dev tools commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), via the [Electron `Debugger` API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/debugger)?

I found that clicking the checkbox in dev tools goes through [this code path](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:out/chromeos-Debug/gen/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/devtools_compatibility.js;l=523;drc=5160b3441179a7db4517a5bdae6539d1a00a5ab2) in Chromium, but otherwise I wasn't able to figure out how I could do this programmatically using the debugger API.

I tried the following:

```js
  mainWindow.webContents.once("dom-ready", async () => {
      const debug = mainWindow.webContents.debugger;
      try {
        debug.attach("1.1");
      } catch (err) {
        // debugger may already be attached
      }

      try {
        await debug.sendCommand("Runtime.enable");
        await debug.sendCommand("Runtime.setCustomObjectFormatterEnabled", { enabled: true });
      } finally {
        debug.detach();
      }
  });
```

But the setting doesn't appear to change.

Comment: CDP has [Runtime.setCustomObjectFormatterEnabled](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-setCustomObjectFormatterEnabled) so you can send it to your app via puppeteer. You'll probably need to launch the app with something like --remote-debugging-port=1234. This should be a one-time action, no need to bind it to opening of devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, I don't know how I missed that. But I tried doing `debugger.sendCommand("Runtime.setCustomObjectFormatterEnabled", { enabled: true })`, and that didn't work. Have you used this before?

Comment: Try asking in their repo. Maybe they intentionally don't implement "experimental" commands.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/28668